# UWP Console / GUI hybrid application

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, uwp, console

I want to create C# UWP app, that:

- starts in GUI mode after double click from explorer
- starts in console mode after execute command in cmd/powershell (examples: `C:\> app_name` displays help for console mode, `C:\> app_name download https://www.url.com/` downloads video from given website)

I know this is possible with WPF, but I couldn't find information about something like this with UWP.

I was able to make the application run after executing the command in console, but then a new window is created (without content, just the app icon) and no output from `Console.WriteLine(str);` is shown in the console.

I was able to do this by adding some lines of code to Package.appxmanifest

`xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"` in `<Package ...>`

And in `<Package><Applications><Application>...</Application></Applications></Package>`:

```
<Extensions>
    <uap5:Extension
     Category="windows.appExecutionAlias"
     Executable="app_name.exe"
     EntryPoint="app_name.App">
        <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
            <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="app_name.exe" />
        </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
    </uap5:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

Now I just have to make the text appear in the console instead of the app window.

Comment: You could refer to [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp#additional-considerations-for-uwp-console-apps) to know how to create a Universal Windows Platform console app. However, it mentions that only C++/WinRT and C++/CX UWP apps may be console apps. So if you use C#, I have to say there is no way to do this.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT It is possible to create a UWP console application in C#. [(Link to Windows Developer Blog)](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/06/06/c-console-uwp-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

I see it. You could add the **`Subsystem="console"`** capability to check if this issue still occurs, which denotes that this UWP app is a console app.  As follows:

```
xmlns:desktop4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/4"
......

  <uap5:AppExecutionAlias desktop4:Subsystem="console">
       <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="app_name.exe" />
  </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
```